# Flexx AttributeError type object IOLoop has no attribute current

Tags: python

[CMD compile Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCZFD.png) I'm learning to use flexx to create a GUI website. This is an example from my professor. When I try to compile it, it returns `AttributeError type object IOLoop has no attribute current`. Why?

```
from flexx import flx

class Example(flx.Widget):

    def init(self):
        flx.Button(text='Hello')
        flx.Button(text='world')

app = flx.App(Example)
app.export('example.html',link=0) #export to singe file
app.launch('browser') #show it now in a broswer
flexx.run() # enter the mainloop
```

Comment: What is the exact error traceback?

Comment: I add it on the link, This is my first question on stackoverflow, sorry for incomplete information

Answer (score 0):

I think we're in same class.
And get same issue.

The reason why is about pyzmq and tornado's version
Try `pip3 install tornado==5` to deupgrade your tornado

Then tornado and pyzmq could work normally.

Comment: btw, I use miniconda. my python version is 3.6.8, pyzmq is 18.0.1(newest) and tornado is 5.0.0(be deupgraded.